# Is $ n^2-14n+24 $ a prime number?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How many are those positive integers n such that Is $ n^2-14n+24 $ is prime ? I have tried to solve this problem by putting different values of natural number . Is it a right way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$n^2−14n+24=(n-2)(n-12)=p \text{ (p prime number)}$$

so

$$(n-2)(n-12) = p*1\text{ or }1*p$$

so

$$n-2=1\text{ and }n-12 =p$$

$n=3$ but it's not answer (it's not prime)

$n-12=1$ and $n-2=p$ then $n=13$ and

$$(n-2)(n-12) =11 *1$$

I think that is only answer

Comment: What about $n=1$? You assumed $n-2 \geq 0$.

Comment: Whats about $(-p)*(-1)$ and $(-1)*(-p)$ ?

Comment: -1 because it is incomplete

Answer (score 11):

*Hint:* $n^2-14n+24 =(n-12)(n-2)$

Comment: That means it can not be a prime .

Comment: @Waytoinfinity No it doesn't mean that. And I assume you have already tried out at least one value of $n$ that *does* produce a prime. (I mean, you said you "tried to solve this problem by putting different values of natural number" - I don't assume your first try was $n=873652$)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: $n=13$ and $n=1$ are the only integer values of $n$ that give a prime number ($11$). Those are the values I'd check first ;-)

Answer (score 3):

> How many are those positive integers n such that Is $n^2−14n+24$ is prime ?

The problem statement is missing a key piece of background information. I hope it is from a competition, because as an instructional assignment from a class or textbook it is wasting students' time by omitting the information and presenting the problem as being of a solvable type, which it is not.

The background is that it is a hard unsolved problem in number theory to prove that $x^2+ax+b$ has infinitely many prime values, if it cannot be factorized as $(x-p)(x-q)$, where $a,b,p,q$ refer to integers.  If you accept that this conjecture is likely to be correct, the only case where the question can be given a provable answer is when a factorization exists.  The question as it is written presents the false impression that given a quadratic function, it is a solvable exercise to derive and prove its number of prime values, and this is an open research problem.

Comment: Well, I for my part do not get the impression that a specific instance of a problem occuring as a beginner's exercise makes makes any claim about a vast generalization. Finding all Pythagorean triples is an often-used beginner's exercise, but that does not suggest that Wiles merely replaced $2$ with $n$.

Comment: n2−14n+24=(n-2)(n-12) =p     (p prime number)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, $14$ and $24$ are random-looking numbers.  And in the beginner context, yes, a lot of people do think that because $x^2+y^2=z^2$ has a nice solution, so should everything else.

Answer (score 0):

If you put an even number you will see that is not prime.

So if $n=2k$, $n^2−14n+24=(2k)^2-14(2k)+24$.

Now factor $4$.

Comment: This does not answer the question.